# How to delete 0 in file?

Tags: bash

how I will remove all spaces before the character that is not equal to 0 in the file?

example

```
000545 - delete 000
0184 - delete 0
000000547 - delete 000000
005000  - delete 00
```

thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

```
sed -e 's/^00*//' file.txt
```

this remove all `0` characters at the beginning of the line.

Comment: One catch might be that this would delete the first number if it happens to be equal to 0

Answer (score 3):

A `sed` way:

```
$ echo '000545
> 0184
> 000000547
> 005000
> ' | sed 's/^0*//'
545
184
547
5000
```

Comment: One catch might be that this would delete the first number if it happens to be equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would be any slower, but goes as a solution, anyway:

```
awk '{printf "%d\n", $1}'
```

or explicitly:

```
awk '{print int($1)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another variant and a bit more generalized and should work for the OP's case as well.

This will remove all leading zeroes but if the line contains either just a `0` or just a set of zeroes it will ensure that exactly one zero is preserved instead of making it blank (which the other answers did). If this behavior is not intended and you merely want to blank out all the lines containing just zeroes, do not use this solution.

```
sed 's#^0\+\([^0]\+.*$\|0$\)#\1#' file
```

Example file:

```
000545
0184
000000547
005000
000a
00000
0
0045b
067800abc
```

Output:

```
545
184
547
5000
a
0
0
45b
67800abc
```

Comment: Yep you're right, I can use the `-e` option of sed :) Updated the post.

Comment: You may just use `sed 's/.../.../...' <file>`; works very nice for me with GNU sed version 4.2.1. The `-e` is usually applied for cases with multiple expressions.

Comment: Right again. Didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this arcane bit of Perl recently: `perl -pe 's/\G0//g'`

Answer (score 0):

Another awk:

```
awk '{$1+=0}1' file
```